# Flutter: Cannot retrieve data from a Future function on FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-future

I'm building a receipt scanner using the Flutter OCR plugin provided by Veryfi.

Here's a Stream function that reads an image and returns a dynamic array containing the necessary values.

Note the credentials from `VeryfiDart` are removed.

The `showImage` variable is an image file either captured from a camera or selected from an image gallery.

```
class ReceiptProcessor {
  Future<dynamic> processReceipt(File image) async {
    List<List<Widget>> itemList = [];

    Uint8List imageData = image.readAsBytesSync();
    String fileData = base64Encode(imageData);
    VeryfiDart client = VeryfiDart(
      'ClientId',
      'ClientSecret',
      'Username',
      'ApiKey',
    );

    await client.processDocument('receipt.jpg', fileData).then(
      (response) {
        String totalPayment = response['total'].toString();
        String currencyCode = response['currency_code'];
        String vendorName = response['vendor']['name'];

        for (var item in response['line_items']) {
          String description = item['description'];
          String quantity = item['quantity'].toString();
          String totalCost = item['total'].toString();

          List<Widget> itemInfo = [
            Text(description),
            Text(quantity),
            Text(totalCost)
          ];
          itemList.add(itemInfo);
        }

        List<dynamic> processedDetails = [
          Text(totalPayment),
          Text(currencyCode),
          Text(vendorName),
          itemList
        ];

        return processedDetails;
      },
    ).catchError((error) {
      return Text('Error');
    });
  }
}
```

Apparently the data are properly fetched, but issues occur when trying to retrieve the data and display it.

```
class ReceiptDetailsView extends StatefulWidget {
  const ReceiptDetailsView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ReceiptDetailsView> createState() => _ReceiptDetailsViewState();
}

class _ReceiptDetailsViewState extends State<ReceiptDetailsView> {
  Future<dynamic> loadProcessedReceipt() async {
    ReceiptProcessor rp = ReceiptProcessor();
    return await rp.processReceipt(showImage!);
  }

  late Future<dynamic> processedReceipt;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    processedReceipt = loadProcessedReceipt();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
        future: processedReceipt,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
              } else if (snapshot.data != null) {
                return Text('Success');
              }
          }
          return Text('Error');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I used a `FutureBuilder` here, but continuously an empty snapshot containing a null data is returned; thus, `'Error'` is displayed on the view.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. A `'Success'` Text should appear when the snapshot data is properly retrieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your function does indeed not return anything. Mostly, because your use of the `then` function. Since you return inside your `then` callback, the value is not returned globally but instead just for this function.

There's two options, you could either return the value that you resolve in the `then` callback like this:

```dart
return await client.processDocument(..).then(...);
```

Or don't use `then` at all, and instead keep relying on `await`:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> response = await client.processDocument(...);
...
return processedDetails;
```

I would recommend the latter case, where the single return simply returns from the function itself, and you don't include some code in a nested callback function.